# Fundamental confusion in SQL and VBA implementation in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am very new to SQL, Visual Basic, and Microsoft Access, and I had a question regarding getting data from a database and computing a value from a user defined function, where the input is only the primary key of the table. My database is set up in the following way

```
    Table1
    Hardware_type  Clock_Speed  Display_Size
                1          600      100000  
                2          300      200000
```

So in my first table the primary key is Hardware type

```
     Table2
     Hardware_Type  Resolution  Preview_Lag  Snapshot_Lag
                 1     8000000         146           92   
                 1    16600000         213           103
     ...
```

This table has a composite key with Hardware type and Resolution being coupled as a key.

What I dont understand is if some one wants to know total lag per frame = (Preview + Snapshot)/(Clock_Speed * 10^6) 
for a certain hardware type with a certain resolution, how does that happen? So I know that I can make a function lets call it Total_Lag but if i need to make the function so that the user only inputs hardware type and resolution and I just output the total lag? ( I assume I can do this as the Hw type and resolution uniquely identifies the row in table 2)

I really need help on this as I am just stumped and stuck on how to write functions that would allow for this functionality. Also the actual database has more complicated formulas and like 50 columns for table 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to study [table joins](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx). This knowledge is fundamental to working with databases.

Comment: So, have you used SQL ever, in any setting?  I will remove the VBA tags as I can't see how they would apply.

Comment: @Smandoli I havent really, this is my first mini project in my internship for the summer, and I am feeling just quite overwhelmed because i have no way on how to do this at all

Comment: You'll have a fun summer.  Access doesn't feed happy results to the beginner as quickly as Excel does, but if you stick with it, great power is yours.  And, welcome to Stack Overflow.  :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible to do but you have a long road because there are alot of concepts to pick up on the way.  Also, Access's graphical designer is very useful for helping you to visualize your code.  Let's break your problem into 2 sections:

1. Learning how to join the 2 tables.  Andy G suggested a link in your comments, but I prefer [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Try playing around with Access's graphical designer then looking at the SQL it generates.  You'll need to decide if you want an inner, left, or outer join.
2. Once you have the data all in one place, doing the calculation.

Try this example SQL Code:

```
Select T1.*,
       T2.*,
       ([Clock_Speed] + [Snapshot]) as Calc
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2 
     on T1.Hardware_Type=T2.Hardware_Type
```

This query *should* give you all the fields in Table1 followed by Table2 followed by a  calculation that combines data from the two (I say *should* because I didn't test it first). When you get stumped, don't be afraid to google various terms and see what comes up.  When you post another problem to SO, please also tell us what you've already tried, even if it's wrong.

Comment: Nice answer.  Does not work out the calculation fully, but that makes sense with your tutorial approach.

Comment: I just had one more question regarding User defined functions for access, if i wanted to write some function in SQL, and then use it in my query, where in microsoft access GUI would I actually write that function so i could reference it in my queries

Comment: @Smandoli, well, when the OP said there more complicated formulas than that, I felt the tutorial approach was best.

Comment: @user3666732, for questions like that, I recommend first asking yourself if you are the first person to ever ask such a question or the 100,000th.  In other words you can probably google it :)  I kind of like this youtube video (it takes the long approach but it also links to other tutorial videos you might like). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DweQttgloM

Answer (score 1):

I second the comments above. There is a steep learning curve ahead.  The SQL statement to perform the calculation you're looking for (without a resolution critierion) is:

```
SELECT Table1.Hardware_type, Table2.Resolution, 
    ([Preview_Lag]+[Snapshot_Lag])/[Clock_Speed]*10^6 AS Calc
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.Hardware_type = Table2.Hardware_Type;
```

which yields the following based on your data:

```
Hardware_type   Resolution                Calc
1                  8000000    396666.666666667
1                 16600000    526666.666666667
```